# Docker usage with Odoo 10.0

Tags: docker, odoo, odoo-10, docker-container

I need to know how to setup a **Docker** to implement a container that could help me run an **Odoo 10.0** ERP environment in it.
I'm looking for references or some setup guides, even I don't mind if you can paste the CLI below. I'm currently developing in a Ubuntu OS.

*Thanks in Advance.......!!!*

Comment: Have you done any research on this topic before posting here? Please share what you have done and base on that I will give you an example.

Comment: I did searched a little bit on my own, but couldn't find a perfect answer and ended up empty handed. It's something similar to virtualenv but it's different in a way & standardly used by companies.

Comment: I have created a solution for you using Docker. Test it and working on it. Make sure you do your research before posting anything. You will end up learning more if you do.

Comment: check answer below

Answer (score 0):

@NaNDuzIRa  This is quite simple. I suggest that when you want to learn how to do something even if you need it very fast to look into the "man page" of the tool that you are trying to use to package your application. In this case, it is Docker.

1. Create a file name Dockerfile or dockerfile
2. Now that you know the OS flavor you want to use. Include that at the beginning of the "Dockerfile"
3. Then, you can add how you want to install your application in the OS.
4. Finally, you include the installation steps of Odoo for which i have added a link at the bottom of this post.

   ```
   #OS of the image, Latest Ubuntu 
   FROM ubuntu:latest

   #Privilege raised to install the application or package as a root user 
   USER root

   #Some packages that will be used for the installation 
   RUN apt update && apt -y install wget

   #installing Odoo 
   RUN  wget -O - https://nightly.odoo.com/odoo.key | apt-key add -
   RUN echo "deb http://nightly.odoo.com/10.0/nightly/deb/ ./" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/odoo.list
   RUN apt-get -y  update && apt-get -y install odoo
   ```

   - References

     1. [Docker](http://www.docker.com)
     2. [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)
     3. [Odoo](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/setup/install.html)

Comment: @NaNDuzIRa you can click up button to acknowledge that you like the response.